# A Better Way to Get Parent of UserControl in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight

On my MainPage.xaml, I sometimes need to add a UserControl to the main Panel (a Canvas). That UserControl, when clicked, needs to access a routine from MainPage.xaml - it's parent's parent - which will either make the UserControl itself `Visibility = Collapsed` or removed all together from MainPage.xaml.

Right now in the code behind of that UserControl I am doing

```
Dim c = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(Me)
Dim mp As MainPage = VisualTreeHelper.GetParent(c)
mp.MyRoutine(3)
```

This is working, but it makes me wonder if there is a more straight-forward way to do this or a more preferred way. Any ideas?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A more general way of navigating the visual tree is available via [Linq To VisualTree](http://www.scottlogic.co.uk/blog/colin/2010/03/linq-to-visual-tree/), with this small framework you can perform all sorts of queries on your visual tree. Your example of getting parent would be as simple as:

```
var parent = me.Ancestors().First();
```

Or, if you want to find the first parent of a given type ...

```
var parent = me.Ancestors<MainPage>().Cast<MainPage>().First()
```

Comment: @ColinE: Shouldn't that be `me.Ancestors().Skip(1).First();`?  He's going up 2 levels in the visual tree...

Comment: The use of `Cast` would generate an exception in this case, I guess you meant `OfType`.

Comment: Nope - I meant cast. Ancestors<T> returns all ancestors of the given type, however the returned enumeration is of type FrameworkElement, thisis because the Linq to VisualTree extensions are on IEnumerable<FrameworkElement> and hence this allows you to perform subsequent Linq queries on the result of the Ancestors<T> operation.

Comment: The link does not lead to the Linq-To-VisualTree project anymore.

Answer (score 4):

In general, I'd avoid this type of dependency.  It dramatically reduces the usefulness and flexibility of your UserControl.

Instead, it might be better to push the dependency into the UserControl during construction (or even runtime).  You could pass in a delegate referencing `MyRoutine`, or an interface the main page implements.

This way, the UserControl's dependency would be obvious (since it's part of the API), and it would be possible to use it with other applications/pages later.

That being said, if you decide to keep the above, I would make one change at a minimum.  Instead of just expecting the parent's parent to always be "MainWindow", I would recursively check parents until you get to the MainWindow (or nothing) in a method on your class.  This would, at a minimum, allow you the flexibility of moving your UserControl around in the hierarchy without breaking it.

Comment: this is interesting, the interface idea. i haven't done much with interface's in the past, but it's worth exploring.

Comment: @Stan: It would make this a much more "reusable" control.  Right now, the UserControl is very tied to your MainWindow class, and only usable in a specific point in the hierarchy...

Answer (score 2):

The general way that I navigate the visual tree is with my own [VisualTreeEnumeration](http://geekswithblogs.net/codingbloke/archive/2010/12/19/visual-tree-enumeration.aspx) code.  However as I state in the blog there are other various utilities to do the same.  Whatever you use you end up with an enumerable set of ancestors.  However the most most flexiable approach would be to hunt for the `MainPage` type:-

(Note C#)

```
MainPage mp = this.Ancestors().OfType<MainPage>().FirstOrDefault();
```

Not sure what this would look like VB.